A point in a set is interior point iff
Definition of interior point: $x$ is interior point of $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ if there exists $\varepsilon >0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon )\subset X$.

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. $a\in A$ is an interior point of $A$ iff for every sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $x_n\to a$, there is a $N_a\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n\in A$ for all $n\geq N_a$.

So far I have:
If $a$ is not an interior point of $A$, this means that for every $\varepsilon>0$, $B(a,\varepsilon)\not\subset A$. Then, it holds that $A^C\bigcap B(a,\varepsilon )\neq\emptyset$ for all $\varepsilon >0$. So, in particular, for every $\varepsilon =1/n$, with $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there is $x_n\in A^C\bigcap B(a,\ 1/n)$.
It follows that $x_n\in A^C$ and $x_n\in B(a,1/n)$. In particular, $||a-x_n||<1/n$.
However, I'm stuck after this.

The condition $x_n\in B(a,\frac{1}{n})$ implies that $x_n\rightarrow x$.

Another hint: Do the hypothesis remind you of Heine's Theorem (which I assume you have learned)? You may try to apply it to $\chi_A$.

Well, you are pretty much done. If $||a-x_n||<\frac{1}{n}$ then $x_n\to a$, and none of the elements of the sequence belongs to $A$.
For the converse, assume $a$ is an interior point of $A$, so pick some $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(a,\epsilon)\subseteq A$. Suppose $x_n\to a$. By definition of convergence we eventually have $||a-x_n||\leq\epsilon$, i.e $x_n\in B(a,\epsilon)\subseteq A$.

Thanks! Just to verify that I understood the converse correctly: Asume $a$ to be an interior point of $A$. Then there exists $r_a>0$ such that $B(a,r_a)\in A$. If $(x_n)$ is a sequence such that $x_n\to a$, then in particular, for $r_a>0$, there is $N_a\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $||a-x_n||<r_a$ for all $n\geq N_a$. In other words, $x_n\in B(a,r_a)\subset A$ for all $n\geq N_a$. Correct?

@user926356 Yes, this is correct.
